# How do I transfer text to a website text area without copying? Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need help I don't know Python very well. I want to print the text area on my website by pulling automatic questions from a text document for a project question bot project.

```
Questions = bro.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nopaste']")
Questions.send_keys("example.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the contents from the "example.txt" file and post the details in the test area.

`send_keys` only takes a string as input and not the file.
I am from Java, but I think it would look something like this:

```
Questions = bro.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nopaste']")
file = open("example.txt", "r") 
Questions.send_keys(file.readlines())
```

Comment: I will try this. I will read the contents of the text document and send it to the website textarea. So is the read function sufficient for this?

Comment: Yes the read function is also enough - all we need to do is read the file contents to a string str = open(example.txt', 'r').read()